# Tab menu with border

Tags: html, css

Currently i have menu like this:

[image]

But I need to add a fill for the selected menu item and the same for home menu item, like next:

[image]

My code is:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tab</title>
    <style>
        .tabs {
            list-style-type: none;
            position: relative;
        }
        .tabs:after {
            content: "";
            clear: both;
            display: block;
        }
        .tabs li {
            float: left;
        }
        .tabs li>input {
            display: none;
        }
        .tabs li>label {
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 8px 30px;
        }
        .tabs .tab-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100vw;
            left: 0;
        }
        .tabs li>input:checked~.tab-content {
            display: block;
        }
        ul {
            background: rgb(65, 63, 63);
            color: white;
        }
        .home {
            background-color: blue;
        }
        .order {
            background-color: green;
        }
        .tab-content {
            padding: 5px;
            border-top: 2px solid white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-1" checked>
            <label for="tab-1" class="home">Home</label>
            <div class="tab-content home"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-2">
            <label for="tab-2" class="order">Order</label>
            <div class="tab-content order"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

How i can add fill for selected menu item? Or maybe I need to somehow break the border and increase the height of the selected menu item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution could be to use a pseudo-element `after` in your label tag:

```
.tabs label:after {
    content: "";
    display: none;
    background-color: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -2px;
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
}

.tabs li>input:checked+label:after {
    display: block;
}
```

```css
.tabs {
 list-style-type: none;
 position: relative;
}

.tabs:after {
 content: "";
 clear: both;
 display: block;
}

.tabs li {
 float: left;
}

.tabs li>input {
 display: none;
}

.tabs li>label {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 8px 30px;
 position: relative;
}

.tabs .tab-content {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100vw;
 left: 0;
}

.tabs li>input:checked~.tab-content {
 display: block;
}

ul {
 background: rgb(65, 63, 63);
 color: white;
}

.home {
 background-color: blue;
}

.order {
 background-color: green;
}

.tab-content {
 padding: 5px;
 border-top: 2px solid white;
}

.tabs li>input:checked+label:after {
 display: block;
}

.tabs label:after {
 content: "";
 display: none;
 background-color: inherit;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 10;
 left: 0;
 bottom: -2px;
 height: 2px;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
   <li>
      <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-1" checked>
      <label for="tab-1" class="home">Home</label>
      <div class="tab-content home"></div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-2">
      <label for="tab-2" class="order">Order</label>
      <div class="tab-content order"></div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's full working code:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.tabbar .tabs>li').forEach(function (c){
  c.addEventListener('click', function(){
    for (var elem of c.parentElement.children) {
      elem.classList.remove('active');
      document.querySelector(elem.getAttribute('page'))
      .classList.remove('active');
    }
    document.querySelector(c.getAttribute('page')).classList.add('active');
    c.classList.add('active');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.tabbar .tabs {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: #aaa;
  margin: 0 0 2px 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.tabbar .pages {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.tabbar .pages>li {
  padding: 15px;
  display: none;
}

.tabbar .pages>li.active {
  display: block;
}

.tabbar .tabs>li {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tabbar .tabs>li.active:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -2px;
  height: 2px;
  background: inherit;
}

.tabbar .tabs>li:nth-child(1),
.tabbar .pages>li:nth-child(1){
  background: blue;
}

.tabbar .tabs>li:nth-child(2),
.tabbar .pages>li:nth-child(2){
  background: green;
}

.tabbar .tabs>li:nth-child(3),
.tabbar .pages>li:nth-child(3){
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabbar">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li page="#page-1">First</li>
    <li page="#page-2" class="active">Second</li>
    <li page="#page-3">Third</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="pages">
    <li id="page-1">Page 1</li>
    <li id="page-2" class="active">Page 2</li>
    <li id="page-3">Page 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```